# missing application icons on OSX

Tags: java, javafx, dmg

My application contains a logo and one of the buttons also has a logo assigned. I use the build.fxbuild to create my build.xml from where I then build my installer.

No problem running the application from the built EXE on a Windows system.

If I build a DMG from an OSX machine however, the application and the button logo are missing. If I run the application within Eclipse (on OSX), they are visible.

Application logo (in main class)

```
Image ico = new Image("file:resources/images/logo.png");
this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(ico);
```

Button (in fxml file)

```
<Button fx:id="testButton" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="150.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#testMethod" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="174.0" style="-fx-graphic: url('file:resources/images/test.png')" text="Test" />
```

What am I missing here?